# wordpress installation issues

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress

I Installed Wordpress under (UBUNTU)`/var/www/wordpress`. `wp-config.php` is modified as recommended.

When trying to access `http://x.y.z.a/wordpress/wp-admin/wp-install.php` it doesn't open the page but instead downloads the file...

Answer (score 2):

You must have to install `xampp` to run `.php` files. Because web browser doesn't understand `.php` files.

PHP files are rendered in Server like Apache and then it work in web browsers.

Comment: Did you read that OP has an Ubuntu server? None of xampp or wamp can run on his server...

Comment: @j0k: There appears to be plenty of tutorials out there for installing xampp under Ubuntu?! I haven't tried; can you confirm? Thanks.

Comment: @w3d oh yeah, you're right. I was (almost) sure that xampp was only available in gui, not in cli.

Comment: @j0k my thoughts exactly why the heck is XAMP being suggested when OP said he's got WordPress installed on Ubuntu. Even if XAMP can install on Ubuntu as w3d decided to point out which is just ridiculous to do IMHO and i'm sure many others agree. Bybe has the best answer update and re-install the proper packages.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not installed or not configured properly on your server, Install LAMP or install php and configure it manually.    There are instructions for doing so here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Edit:

If php is installed but still there is the same issue of being downloaded, it means that the apache/php configuration is not done right.

If you have recently installed any plugins relating to php and apache, make sure to restart apache before the new settings take effect:

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

If still not working, try to follow the recommendation in here: https://serverfault.com/questions/215455/what-causes-php-pages-to-consistently-download-instead-of-running-normally

If that is too hard because you are not experienced with linux/ubuntu, then you should uninstall apache/php/mysql, and reinstall them again, which should make the appropriate settings, but this time follow a guide from the start like the one posted above.

Comment: Hello Stephen Ostermiller - I need your help. I have spent many days to solve this issue and I am not going anywhere. I looked at the page that you sent me and I checked apache and php looks like both are running in my server. I also wrote a test.php and I tried to open it but it is also getting downloaded. I know I am close to it but I cannot make that working. Please help.

Comment: one more data point that I want to share is that I am operating everything under root. I have not created any user yet.

Comment: @Prasad I have edited the post with more info.

Comment: Thanks Sharp. I will your suggestions and I will let you know.

Comment: @sharp12345 he said he's installed WordPress on Ubuntu, why would you say to install LAMP as if LAMP is some application. He's already on Linux. bybe has posted a better answer

Comment: Hello Sharp, I tried "sudo apache2ctl -M" and it is not listing "php5_module (shared)" as one of the modules. Would this be the problem? Please, Please help.

Answer (score 2):

***You need to install PHP5 which is really easy just follow my 5 simple steps and voila your done.***

1. Connect to your Ubuntu using SSH or bring up the terminal if using Desktop.
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install php5
4. sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
5. sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

All done and PHP should now work, you may run into MySQL problems if you have not installed this either... let us know if you encounter any more problems and I'll assist.

**PHP5 installed but prompted to download php file**

1. Enable mod_write - `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
2. Enable .htaccess `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` find the lines with the directory setting i.e /var/www find `AllowOverride none` and change to `AllowOverride All`
3. Now create a blank .htaccess file if you don't have one already `sudo nano /var/www/.htaccess` add the following line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html` and this one below it `AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .htm .html`
4. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Hello bybe , I did the steps that you suggested, I still get the file downloaded. :( Please help

Comment: When I run >>>>> sudo a2enmod php5                                                         
It says >>>>>>>> Module php5 already enabled

Comment: Just updated my answer. give that a true. Basiclly if you have PHP installed then the problem is that it doesn't understand the MIME and you need to AddType Application.